# Can't connect to Azure VM RDP on Remote Desktop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-vm

I have been trying to connect to connect to my virtual machine via RDP on "Microsoft Remote Desktop".
I have set port 3389 as the destination port in "inbound" rule on VM. Even the test connection of RDP shows "Network connectivity allowed".
However, the remote desktop pop up the error message "Unable to connect". I tried deploying the VM again. But still I get that error.

Can anybody help me with this? I have been stuck on this for weeks!! Thanks in advance.

[image: TEST CONNECTION WITH RDP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not listed in the question, but if this is a Windows 10 VM you will need to enable Remote Desktop first.  Please update the question with the OS.

**How to enable Remote Desktop**

The simplest way to allow access to your PC from a remote device is using the Remote Desktop options under Settings. Since this functionality was added in the Windows 10 Fall Creators update (1709), a separate downloadable app is also available that provides similar functionality for earlier versions of Windows. You can also use the legacy way of enabling Remote Desktop, however this method provides less functionality and validation.

Windows 10 Fall Creator Update (1709) or later
You can configure your PC for remote access with a few easy steps.

1. On the device you want to connect to, select **Start** and then click the **Settings** icon on the left.
2. Select the **System** group followed by the Remote Desktop item (or just search for "Remote Desktop").
3. Use the slider to enable Remote Desktop.
4. It is also recommended to keep the PC awake and discoverable to facilitate connections.
5. Click **Show settings** to enable.
   As needed, add users who can connect remotely by clicking **Select users that can remotely access this PC**.

   - Members of the Administrators group automatically have access.
6. Make note of the name of this PC under How to connect to this PC. You'll need this to configure the clients.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access